# Callback mechanism of Java 8

Tags: java, callback, closures, java-8

What is the best and easiest way to implement callback mechanism in java 8? 
Is it to easily replace inner class decleration with lambda experission? 
Like replacing

```
    doSomethingAndRunThisCode(new Call() {

        @Override
        public void callback() {
            System.out.println("here I am called back");

        }
    });
```

with

```
doSomethingAndRunThisCode(() -> {
        System.out.println("here I am called back");

    });
```

But I think this is not all. Because pre java 8 way is even easier due to code complition of eclipse. Eclipse does nothing on java 8 way of implementing it (yet) .

Comment: So you are saying that those 7 lines of mostly boilerplate code are "easier" than the elegant `doSomethingAndRunThisCode(System.out::println)`?

Comment: easier to write. because when you type new keyword and press CTRL+Space+Enter eclipse(and probably other IDEs too) does the rest for you. But the java 8 way is easier to read undoubtedly.

Comment: That’s a strange measurement. Eclipse will insert that boilerplate on `CTRL+Space` but it will only insert the very stuff that is obsolete with lambdas. To be more exact, with your example you have to write at least `new C` before asking for completion to get the suggestion of creating an anonymous inner class. With Java 8 lambda you have to write `()->` before you can enter the real code (which does not differ from the inner classes’ code). So, ignoring space, you need to type four characters in both cases, but for the inner class *only if* eclipse suggests the right thing on the first guess.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can replace the inner class definition.  So long as the interface being expected by the method you are calling has 1 unimplemented method, you can use the lambda syntax.

So what you did above is correct.  Also, as someone pointed out, there is the function reference syntax, but that function reference you pass has to have a signature that is coercable to your interface. For instance, take the Consumer interface:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
   void accept(T t);
}

public class MyClass { 
   void doSomething(Consumer<String> consumer) { }
}
```

In this case, you can pass any function reference to the "doSomething" method which has a void return, and accepts a single parameter as a string.

ie.
    myClassInstance.doSomething(System.out::println);

I'm not sure about eclipse, as i haven't used the latest versions, but I know Intellij 13 supports the lambda syntax.  And even if you're not using java8, it will fold your code into that syntax to make it easier to read (don't worry, it doesn't save it that way, it's just a presentation thing that you can unfold if desired).